# Cannot resolve symbol show

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the code. Basic task of the application is to get a random number and then user has to guess it. When I'm trying to run the app there are some errors, I was looking for a typo but I don't get why it isn't working. The problem is with the "setText" atribute. Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package pl.zgadula.zgadnijliczbe;

import android.content.Context; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

import static android.R.id.message; import static pl.zgadula.zgadnijliczbe.R.id.strzal; import static pl.zgadula.zgadnijliczbe.R.id.textView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int myNumber, userNumber, guessCount=0 ;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void newGame(View view) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        myNumber = rand.nextInt((100-0)+1)+0;
        guessCount = 0;
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Ile razy zgadywałeś: " + guessCount);
    }

    public void takeTheGuess(View view) {

        guessCount++;

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        userNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        String message = "";

        if(userNumber>myNumber){
            message = "Moja liczba jest mniejsza niż Twoja";
        }
        else if (userNumber<myNumber){
            message = "Moja liczba jest większa od Twojej";
        }
        else if (userNumber==myNumber){
            message = "Gratulacje! To poprawna liczba!";
        }
    }

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
    toast.show();
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Ile razy zgadywałeś: " + guessCount) 
}
```

Comment: On what line exactly you are getting this error and on what operation?

Comment: you miss `;` in line `textView.setText("Ile razy zgadywałeś: " + guessCount)`

Comment: The 61 and 63 lines. Something's wrong with them. "Cannot resolve symbol setText"

Comment: We don't know what are line 61 and 63.

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
    toast.show();
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Ile razy zgadywałeś: " + guessCount)

Comment: You miss `;` after guestCount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines should be part of a method, but you have written them outside of methods:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
toast.show();
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Ile razy zgadywałeś: " + guessCount);
```

Comment: That was helpful, now everything works! Thanks!

Comment: @Alcyone127 You are welcome !!